# Opening webview when the image button is clicked

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I have written a code, when the image button is clicked in Activity1, the webview must be opened in Activity2 with the respective link address which have been provided as a string. When I ran the below code It showed no error in the console, but when I clicked the image button the app was closing. it failed to get to activity 2. Can somebody help me to overcome this issue?

```
Mainactivity.java
package com.example.gptapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageButton button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void openLinkInBrowser(View view) {
button=findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
sendData();
}
});

}
public void sendData(){
String url = "https://youtube.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activitylink.class);
intent.putExtra(Activitylink.website,url);
startActivity(intent);

}

}

Activity 2

package com.example.gptapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class Activitylink extends AppCompatActivity {
private BroadcastReceiver MyReceiver = null;
public static String website;
private String websiteURL;// sets web url
public WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activitylink);
Intent intent = getIntent();
websiteURL = intent.getStringExtra(website);


//Webview stuff
webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
}

}



Activitymain.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton"
android:layout_width="222dp"
android:layout_height="307dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/finalpic"
android:onClick="openLinkInBrowser"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know where is the error occured, but you can try catch `openLinkInBrowser()` block and print log if there has exception.
And you can just keep `sendData();` in `openLinkInBrowser()` method, if you set the listener to the button again, it will override listener in xml you define.